# AttributeError query

Tags: python, properties, getter, setter

***My code:***

```
class Produto:
    def __init__(self,nome,preco):
        self.nome = nome
        self.preco = preco

    def desconto(self,percentual):
        self.preco = self.preco - (self.preco*(percentual/100))

    @property
    def preco(self):
        return self._preco

    @preco.setter
    def preco(self,valor):
        if isinstance(valor,str):
            valor = float(valor.replace('R$',''))
        self._preco = valor


p1 = Produto('camisa', 'R$50')
p1.desconto(20)
print(p1.preco)
```

Return:

> 40

This code work 100% , but, if i change this part:

```
@preco.setter
def preco(self,valor):
    if isinstance(valor,str):
        valor = float(valor.replace('R$',''))
    self._preco = valor
```

For:

```
@preco.setter
def preco(self,valor):
    valor = float(valor.replace('R$',''))
    self._preco = valor
```

***I have this error:***

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

***Why?***

***Another error:***
If i change the same part for:

```
@preco.setter
def preco(self,valor):
    valor = int(50)
    self._preco = valor
p1 = Produto('camisa', 'R$50')
p1.desconto(10)
print(p1.preco)
```

***He Return***

> 50

***Why he dont return 45?***

Comment: Your error has _nothing_ to do with properties or getters or setters. You get the `AttributeError` because `float` objects don't have a member function `replace()` -- `str` objects, on the other hand, do. `if isinstance(valor, str):` checks to make sure `valor` is a `str`.

Comment: _You_ set `valor = int(50)` yourself before you use it to set the value of `self._preco = valor`! Why are you surprised that its value is what you set it to?

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: So before using "replace" do I have to check if it is 'str'?

Comment: valor = int(50) -> Yes, but I define p1.desconto(10) , he just ignore this line and don't change the value.

Comment: Use a debugger. Add a breakpoint on the first line of the `desconto` method and the `preco` setter. See what happens. `desconto()` calls the `preco` setter to set its value. In the setter, you discard the actual value and set it to `50` instead.

Comment: Well, i made its, and: `self.preco = self.preco - (self.preco*(percentual/100))`  -> After this, the call again for `@preco.setter` . For resolve, i change for: `self._preco = self.preco - (self.preco*(percentual/100))` . if he have a same name, happens a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i make a debug.
In:

```
self.preco = self.preco - (self.preco*(percentual/100))
```

Happens a loop, he make a operation, but after this he return for setters and change again the value, for resolve this i change this for:

```
self._preco = self.preco - (self.preco*(percentual/100))
```

In the first attempt , a loop happens too, but

```
if isinstance(valor,str):
```

make a value change only 1 time .

This resolve both problem.